# Why wouldn't one just use chmod 777?

Tags: unix, file-permissions, exchange

I am looking for more information about Unix based systems, and there was a link:

[Permissions in Unix on Mac](https://superuser.com/search?q=change+permissions+in+unix+on+mac+)

about using permissions on Unix on the Mac.

> The basic `chmod` command goes:
>    `$ chmod ### directory/filename`

Why wouldn't one just put:

> `$ chmod 777 directory/filename`

Wouldn't that allow

> - `drwx------` : directory accessible only by owner
> - `drwxr-xr-x` : directory anyone can access
> - `-rwxr-xr-x` : file anyone can read and execute
> - `-rw-r-----` : file only people in the group can read

to be

> `drwxrwxrwx` : directory anyone could access?

Comment: (1) I sense that you’re trying to ask a question about Unix permissions, and I’d like to answer it, but I have no idea what you’re asking.  I suggest that you look at [Understanding Unix permissions and their attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/23408) and [How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/23408) If you still have a question, try to make it clearer. (2) If you want to refer to a question / thread or other page, link to it; please don’t link to a search page.

Comment: I want to apologize if the question doesn't seem clear. I'm trying to be logical but I am somewhat visual and spacial in my thinking. My intention to asking this question is that I am the admin of a home network and I have a network of both Mac and Windows users. I have two MBP's and one iMac, one Mac Mini, iPad, iPod, Nano, and one Windows Home Edition machine. I want everyone to be able to access files no matter what within our network, but not anyone who comes over and can access our network.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently dangerous about using

```
$ chmod 777 directory/filename
```

but you need to be careful/selective as to which files/directories you apply it to.

This is because it makes **all users** able to read, write, and execute and this can be dangerous. This applies to your user profile, other users on that computer/OS, and possibly hackers from outside your machine that have breached it. If anyone other user got into your system that was unauthorized, they could view the data within, delete the file altogether, execute it for some malicious gain, etc.

That being said, there are **other** ways to set permissions with chmod that don't give quite as much freedom and you should make use of these other methods to give the **least permission to any file as possible.** But when you use the above command, this is giving the directory/filename the **most** possible permission.

For example, use
`$ chmod u+x filename`
if you wanted to give permissions to just the user for just this file. For more beginner examples, see [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/chmod-command-examples/).

Comment: Thank you, Alexander. I didn't know a hacker could access one's home network and change files on the fly like you are saying above.

Comment: @ChristopherStapleton On a day to day basis, if you're just using your personal 'nix machine on your home network, you're mostly safe from hackers and malicious users getting easy access to your file system. But it's important to build good habits when setting permissions and not set your machine up for failure at a later date. The danger may not come from another user directly but a program with malicious scripts that takes advantage of permissions that are too generous. The implications involved with setting permissions are huge and you should keep your system as locked down as possible.